# Creating a global spinner by using React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I would like to create a reusable spinner, but I have no idea what is the best approach to achieve it.

I've tried 2 methods, but need some opinion, because I am very new to React.

**Method 1:**

MyComponent.js

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    ...
    return (
        ...
        <Progress showProgress={props.Info.processing} />
        ...
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        Info: state.Info,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Progress.js

```
const Progress = (props) => {
    ...
    return (
        <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={props.showProgress || false}>
            <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
        </Backdrop>
    );
};
export default React.memo(Progress);
```

myReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    processing: false,
    error: null,
    data: []
    ...
}
const MyReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case START_PROCESSING: 
            return {...state, processing: true};
        case STOP_PROCESSING: 
            return {...state, processing: false};
    ...         
}
```

For this method 1, it will based on the "processing" flag to render the spinner, but I need to import and add  to every component when I need a spinner.

**Method 2**

Index.js

```
import Progress from "common/components/Progress";
ReactDOM.render(
    ...
    <Progress />
    ...,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

layoutReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    showProgress: false,
    ...
}
const LayoutReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === SHOW_PROGRESS) {
        return {
          ...state,
          showProgress: action.isShow,
        };
    }
    return state;
}
export default LayoutReducer;
```

Progress.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
...

const progressRoot = document.getElementById("progress-root");
const el = document.createElement("div");

const Progress = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    progressRoot.appendChild(el);
  }, []);
  return createPortal(
    <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={props.Layout.showProgress}>
      <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
    </Backdrop>,
    el
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { Layout: state.Layout };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Progress);
```

For this method 2 I am using createPortal, and control the spinner from layoutReducer. But there is a problem for me, if I want to show the spinner from other component when I fetch data, I need to use dispatch(showProgress(true)) to the layoutReducer.
But I am prefer to use own initialState (processing) from each reducer, such as my method 1. let's say I have createReducer, it should use the processing flag from createReduer to control hide/show the spinner instead of I manually call the dispatch to layoutReducer.

So my question is, how to create a global spinner, and it will based on each component's "props.processing" flag to hide/show the spinner?

Updated: am I able to achieve it by creating custom hook? Hook is isolated state is that mean it's not possible to share the state? For example, I want to just import and call the useSpinner() on the the component which need a spinner control. From this hook, it will control the spinner based on my component props. But how? If someone could show some sample code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go with method 1, since method 1 allows you to reuse your component flexibly as and when needed in any other component, which you lose in case of method 2

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution looks overly complicated to me.

To make the Progress spinner as reusable as possible, just make it accept a boolean prop as to whether it should be showing or not, your first solution is on the right track.

Trying to have one global spinner that is only used once, but somehow triggered by every component, is quite probably not worth the extra effort. Keep it Simple.